# Array of text for uilabels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**The scenario is this:**

I have a collection view with different images all going through one `Cell / Cell ID` & I need to be able to Apply labels that are individual names to each of these different pictures.

I understand the method of how to change one label & to apply numbers that are in ascending order. 1,2,3,4, etc as follows:

```
cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section];
```

I'm trying to find a way that is a similar method which will allow me to create a list   to separate the different labels for the different images???

**The question is this: How do I apply individual names/labels to different images pragmatically????**

I can't be much more clearer than this.

Explanation is as simplest terms as possible, also appreciated :)

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: anyway, I'm sure it's not an Xcode but a Cocoa Touch API question. Tag purged.

Comment: not clear, your question

Comment: @user2834596 what do you think UILabel is part of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the names/labels you want to apply and use this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfLabelTexts=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Label1", @"Label2", nil];
cell.label.text=[arrayOfLabelTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Normally you should create your array in e.g. viewDidLoad and in your .h file and use it here.